# Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 (SM-T210R) won't turn on or charge

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-7

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 and for years it worked very well until last year, out of a sudden, it stopped working. It didn't want to charge or turn on.

When I plugged it to my PC, the PC wouldn't detect that it was connected.

I returned back on the issue to try to fix it but the problem is that I don't know what I can do to fix it.

Comment: The PC won't detect the phone if it's turned off though. Have you tried different chargers/adapters, electric ports, and USB cables? Or try buying/replacing the battery? Otherwise, the internal hardware may have a defect, which is possibly out of the scope of this community to DIY fix it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open up the back cover of the tablet.
2. Disconnect the battery from the motherboard.
3. Plug in the charger and let it attempt to charge for 30 seconds.
4. Disconnect the charger and hold the power button for 30 seconds.
5. Connect the battery again and close the tablet back up.

This worked for reviving my Tab 3 Lite 7.0 with the same chipset, but *it has not been tested on the Tab 3 7.0*.